# How to fix code so ball moves and bounces correctly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have to make a pong game for my final project on unity. Everything else is working fine other than the ball. It only moves sometimes when I press play and only bounces back and forth horizontally. I would like to know how to make the ball bounce more realistically.

I have tried editing the code and watching videos, but nothing else is working.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Newball : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 5f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        float sx = Random.Range(0, 2) == 0 ? -1 : 1;
        float sy = Random.Range(0, 2) == 0 ? -1 : 1;

        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(speed * sx, speed * sy, 0f);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    }
}
```

I expect the ball to bounce of the paddles randomly and more realistically, but all it does is go back and forth.

Comment: Are you creating a new ball each time it hits a paddle? Otherwise, you should be moving the ball incrementally inside of the update function

Comment: and how would I go about that?

Comment: The `Start` and `Update` lifecycle events of the Unity3D system are pretty basic components. I would suggest going through the [Scripting Basics](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EventFunctions.html) for the `Update` documentation

Comment: This question should **not** be closed. This is a standard question in Unity3d bringing effort to many readers when properly answered. There actually is a trial approach, even if the author does not understand the instance methods, likewise many others do not. The problem is not that broad using the Unity3d engine features, so a directive answer will be found.

Comment: The basic way, not a complete answer: You should use the physics engine (`Rigidbody` already does) and apply *forces* on collision (use colliders). Physics are updated in the `FixedUpdate()` method.